# Custom shortcut for a ribbon button

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want users to be able to copy product number from the main grid of Products entity.

For this I added the button that does a request for product number and puts it into clipboard with `window.clipboardData.setData('text', 'P/N')`.

But to make it easier ribbon button must have a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

How can I assign shortcut to a button in a supported way?

What are my unsupported options?

Answer (score 0):

The only options I know of is

1) Inside IE, you can use the execCommand('copy') feature.  You'll have to highlight the text inside a textbox to actually copy it though.

2) Use the flash add in ZeroClipboard

https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard

Either way, it's unsupported really.